# How do I make a word-predicting sequential model with a different output size than input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I'm new to Tensorflow/Keras and am having trouble trying to implement a certain Sequential model. I want to make a word-predicting model that has a smaller output than input so that. I am basing my model, training, and predicting off of MIT's Intro to Deep Learning lab:

https://github.com/aamini/introtodeeplearning_labs/blob/master/lab1/Part2_music_generation_solution.ipynb

Here's the model I currently have that works and trains fine:

```
vocab_input_size = 300       # This contains all vocab
vocab_output_size = 100      # This contains only a portion of the input vocab


embedding_dim = 256
rnn_units = 1024
batch_size = 16


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_input_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
    tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_input_size)
])



def compute_cat_loss(labels,logits):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels,logits,from_logits=True)

def compute_cat_accuracy(labels,logits):
    return tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(labels,logits)


EPOCHS = 10
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")


for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

    hidden = model.reset_states()

    for inp, target in dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(inp)
            loss = compute_cat_loss(target, predictions)
            accuracy = compute_cat_accuracy(target, predictions)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

        loss_history.append(loss.numpy().mean())
        acc_history.append(accuracy.numpy().mean())

    model.save_weights(checkpoint_prefix.format(epoch=epoch))
```

As you can see, the Dense layer has the entire vocab size as the output size. However, I want to revise the model so that it has an input of vocab_input_size and an output of vocab_output_size.

Here is what I tried (all that changed is the Dense layer):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_input_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
    tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_output_size)
])
```

The code runs, but there is no loss and zero accuracy; the model isn't training at all. How can I change the model I have so that it trains with a different-sized input than output? Let me know if I need to provide any additional details. Thank you!

Comment: Did you update the training data to account for a smaller output?

Comment: Can you add your compile line, loss function and optimization function

Comment: @JakeP my data currently consists of integer arrays. Inp and target are of shape (16,10), which is (batch_size, seq_length). I don't know how I would be able to change my training data. I included the training code up above

Comment: the model tries to make the output as close to the target as possible.  If the output array and target array have different lengths, I don't know how the model is supposed to make them as close as possible.  I assume they are different lengths because the training data must have had a length of `vocab_input_size` before you made the change.

Comment: @JakeP vocab_input_size is the number of unique words; the actual data has around 3000 words consisting of those unique words. vocab_output_size consists of a number of those unique words. So are you saying that with the model I have, I won't be able to have a different-sized output than input?